# Filter struts2 could not be initialized

Tags: configuration, struts2, websphere-7

I initially wanted to migrate a JAVA EE project into Maven. However, I ran into a dispatching error.
I got this stack trace in the file :
C:\Program Files using(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\My_SERVER\SystemOut.log

```
> [22/03/18 07:46:32:755 VET] 00000020 XmlConfigurat I
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
> Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml] [22/03/18 07:46:32:766
> VET] 00000020 XmlConfigurat I
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
> Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml] [22/03/18 07:46:32:812
> VET] 00000020 XmlConfigurat I
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
> Parsing configuration file [struts.xml] [22/03/18 07:46:32:814 VET]
> 00000020 DefaultConfig I
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
> Overriding property struts.i18n.reload - old value: false new value:
> true [22/03/18 07:46:32:814 VET] 00000020 DefaultConfig I
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
> Overriding property struts.configuration.xml.reload - old value: false
> new value: true [22/03/18 07:46:32:858 VET] 00000020 Dispatcher    E
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
> Dispatcher initialization failed
>                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
>   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:140)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:509)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:423)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:282)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:340)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:812)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:917)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:924)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:852)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)   at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)     at
> com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527) Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
>   ... 40 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> ognl.OgnlRuntime (initialization failure)     at
> java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)    at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
>   ... 45 more
> 
> [22/03/18 07:46:32:860 VET] 00000020 webapp        E
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Erreur du
> servlet]-[ognl.OgnlRuntime (initialization failure)] :
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Class:
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector File:
> ContainerImpl.java Method: inject Line: 295 -
> com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:295:-1  at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:428)    at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:140)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:509)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:423)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:282)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:340)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:812)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:917)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:924)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:852)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)   at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)     at
> com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527) Caused by:
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:295)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:431)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$5.create(ContainerBuilder.java:207)
>   at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$3.create(ContainerBuilder.java:93)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:487)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$7.call(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder.create(ContainerBuilder.java:484)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.createBootstrapContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:252)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
>   ... 27 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:293)
>   ... 40 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> ognl.OgnlRuntime (initialization failure)     at
> java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)    at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.setContainer(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:85)
>   ... 45 more
> 
> [22/03/18 07:46:32:873 VET] 00000020 srt           W
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader WARNING:
> Cannot set header. Response already committed. [22/03/18 07:46:32:874
> VET] 00000020 srt           W
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setHeader WARNING:
> Cannot set header. Response already committed. [22/03/18 07:46:32:875
> VET] 00000020 srt           W
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setHeader WARNING:
> Cannot set header. Response already committed. [22/03/18 07:46:32:875
> VET] 00000020 srt           W
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setDateHeader WARNING:
> Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

I added this dependency to my POM.xml (I thought that it's missing)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I still have the error.
Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Is it perhaps because I'm using Eclipse NEON1?

I have JDK1.7.0_71 and Websphere 7.0.0.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71

MAVEN_HOME=D:\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javassist dependency was messing.
I added this dependeny on the POM file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version> 
</dependency>
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 ognl.OgnlRuntime (initialization failure)  at
```

You have missing OGNL dependencies on class path at run time.

The `xwork-core` is transitive dependency for `struts2-core` artifact.

OGNL is also transitive dependency.

Regarding the second error:

```
Response has been already commuted.
```

Struts is trying to return error result by using servlet response internally or forward to the error page by it can't do it if response has been commuted. The response becomes commuted as soon as the buffer is flushed. You should check the size of buffer on the response object and how much bytes has written to it.

Comment: how can I check the size of buffer on the response object ?

Comment: By calling `getBufferSize()`.

Comment: I added OGNL dependency but still doesn't work ... I don't know where to check the size of buffer , could you help please ?

Comment: @Alma Don't just randomly add dependencies: OGNL is pulled in by Struts 2. You either have a completely hosed dependency list and you're pulling in the wrong stuff manually, or you're not running what you think you are. Take a step back, fix your pom.xml, redeploy.

Comment: @Alma The size of buffer is the second error that you have posted. You should fix the first one. To help you I would add that version of Struts you have used is too old and contains a lot of bugs, so updating the version of jars is going automatically if you change core version. Although I would' recommend you doing it because your code might not work with the new an up to date version of Struts framework. But without updating you can't resolve all errors that might come to your server.

Comment: @Alma If this answer helped you you must mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of error `Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized` would have detail error message in websphere log file, so find detail message e.g. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and add related dependency. check     `<featureManager>` in `server.xml` may help.

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```